# Chrome driver issue in selenium + java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've downloaded latest chrome drivers which is 110 as per the browser version, added path for latest version but it still starting the older version of chrome driver which is 108 and url is not getting opened in chrome.

why its not starting the latest chrome drivers?

Comment: just a guess, but you may have 2 entries for PATH.  You may want to include your driver initialization code.

Comment: do you have chromedriver installed in the python folder?